# MonoDevelop Addin: how to set the CopyToOutput build option in the "xpt.xml" file

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I was wonder how you set the "Copy to output directory" option to "copy if newer" when making MonoDevelop Addins for new project types??

Take this block of code for example, ... what do I need to add to get the "manifest.json" to copy to the output directory at build time?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Template originator = "Andrew Witte">

    <TemplateConfiguration>
        <_Name>MonoNaCl Project</_Name>
        <_Category>C#/MonoNaCl</_Category>
        <LanguageName>C#</LanguageName>
        <_Description>Creates a MonoNaCl project.</_Description>
    </TemplateConfiguration>

    <!-- Actions -->
    <Actions>
        <Open filename = "Internal.c"/>
        <Open filename = "Main.cs"/>
    </Actions>

    <Combine name = "${ProjectName}" directory = ".">
        <Options>
            <StartupProject>${ProjectName}</StartupProject>
        </Options>
        <References>
            <Reference type="Gac" refto="System" />
        </References>
        <Project name = "${ProjectName}" directory = "." type = "MonoNaCl">
            <Options Target = "Exe"/>
            <Files>
<File name="manifest.json">
<![CDATA[{
"name": "MonoNaCl",
  "description": "Mono for NaCl project.",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icons": {
  },
  "requirements": {
    "3D": {
      "features": ["css3d", "webgl"]
    }
  },
  "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "${ProjectName}.html"
    }
}
}
]]></File>
</Files>
        </Project>
    </Combine>
</Template>
```

Comment: @7sharp9 Ya I had to manually copy the files myself when the project builds.  The codes out of date but here is what I did: https://github.com/reignstudios/ReignSDK/blob/master/Tools/MonoDevelop.MonoNaCl/MonoDevelop.MonoNaCl/Projects/MonoNaClProject.cs#L398

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible currently without [modifying core](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/monodevelop-3.0.5/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/SingleFileDescriptionTemplate.cs#L59) to add an attribute for this, or [registering a custom template type](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/monodevelop-3.0.5/main/src/addins/AspNet/MonoDevelop.AspNet/MonoDevelop.AspNet.addin.xml#L96).

However, TBH instead of copy-to-output I'd go with a custom build action and a build extension that would copy files with that build action.

Comment: I thought there would of been a way of setting the build action to Content in the template.  It seems strange that not many people have had a need to do this?

Comment: You can set the build action on a File using the BuildAction attribute. Most of the templates don't because they rely on projects to automatically set the correct build action based on the file type or location.

Comment: But the "Content" build action doesn't mean anything unless you have custom MSBuild targets or a custom project build extension that handles it.